# It was so funny that I 'could not stop laughing'

Tags: expression-choice

What other expressions can I use give the idea of " seeming unable to stop from laughing" because of a very amusing joke or a very funny story ?

Comment: http://itsjustwordplay.blogspot.in/2007/09/hes-so-funny.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **[Barrel of laughs](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/barrel+of+laughs)** something or someone who is very funny Example:  This board game is a barrel of laughs.

&

> **[A laugh a minute](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+laugh+a+minute)** very funny and entertaining Paul's clever screenplay makes this new comedy a laugh a minute.

Answer (score 2):

[Split one's sides with laughter](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/split+sides)  refers to an exaggerated laughter:

> Fig. to laugh so hard that one's sides almost split. (Always an exaggeration.) The members of the audience almost split their sides with laughter. When I heard what happened to Patricia, I almost split my sides.